# How is this function being made use of?

Tags: java, function

I am just studying a few classes given to me by my lecturer and I can't understand how the function `heapRebuild` is being made used of! It doesn't change any global variables and it doesn't print out anything ad it doesn't return anything - so should this even work? It shouldn't, should it?

If you were told to make use of `heapRebuild` to make a new function `removeMac` would you edit `heapRebuild`?

```
public class MaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Heap<T>{
private T[] heap;
private int lastIndex;

public T removeMax(){
        T rootItem = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[lastIndex-1];
        lastIndex--;
        heapRebuild(heap, 0, lastIndex);
        return rootItem;
}

protected void heapRebuild(T[ ] items, int root, int size){

        int child = 2*root+1;
        if( child < size){
            int rightChild = child+1;
            if ((rightChild < size) &&
                    (items[rightChild].compareTo(items[child]) > 0)){
                child = rightChild;
            }
            if (items[root].compareTo(items[child]) < 0){
                T temp = items[root];
                items[root] = items[child];
                items[child] = temp;
                heapRebuild(items, child, size);}
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: what is removeMac referencing?  As in what is a MAC in this instance

Comment: It are *methods*, not *functions*. Java is an OO language, not a procedural language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is a pass-reference-by-value OO language. The methods can change the passed-in mutable values.

Simplified example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] strings = new String[] { "foo", "bar" };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)); // [foo, bar]
        changeValue(strings);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)); // [foo, foo]
    }

    public static void changeValue(String[] strings) {
        strings[1] = "foo";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
T temp = items[root];
items[root] = items[child];
items[child] = temp;
```

These lines swap two entries in `items`, the ones at index `root` and index `child`. Each invocation of `heapRebuild()` works with the same `items` array, not copies of the array, so these changes are indeed seen by the caller.

Answer (score 3):

It modifies the `items` array.

When you pass an object to a function in Java, it doesn't make a separate copy of the object.

Therefore, when your `heapRebuild` function modifies the `items` array, it modifies the original array that was passed to it.

Note that Java does not pass references to variables, so that if the function wrote `items = whatever`, the caller's array will still refer to the old array instance.

Answer (score 1):

Who said it is not doing anything. It modifies the value that is passed which is T[] items.

Answer (score 0):

The method is modifying the passed in array. In java this is passed in by reference. More details [here](http://www.javacertificate.net/passbyvalue.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The method changes the order of the contents of its `T[ ] items` parameter. in Java, method parameters of a reference type (including arrays) are passed by copying the value of the reference. The method can make any changes allowed by the objects those references refer to.